# Preloading Images in JavaScript (Need an Alert When Completed)

Tags: javascript

I have the following code below, which successfully preloads images into the browser cache when the `PreloadAllImages` function is called. Does anyone know how to send a simple alert, e.g. "All images have been preloaded into the browser cache." when the last image (or all images) is loaded. I have 300 images, so `setTimeOut` won't work for latency/download lag reasons. I've tried callbacks, placing alert commands in different places, etc... but have not been successful.

This code is based on JavaScript Only Method #1 found here. https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

```
function PreLoadAllImages() {
  var images = new Array();
  function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
  }

  preload('Images/Image1.jpg', 'Images/Image2.jpg', ... , 'Images/Image300.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help, this is how the problem was solved in case anyone else needs it. Loaded images into an invisible div on the html page, then ran script to ensure everything was loaded. A button calls PreLoadAllImages() and then CheckImages().

```
var imagefiles = [
"Images/Image1.jpg",
"Images/Image2.jpg",
.....
"Images/Image300.jpg"];

function PreLoadAllImages () {
    imagefiles.forEach(function(image){
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = image;
        document.body.appendChild(img);});
    $('img').hide();
} 

var all_loaded;

function CheckImages() {
    $('img').each(function(){ // selecting all image element on the page
    var img = new Image($(this)); // creating image element
    img.src = $(this).attr('src'); // pass src to image object
    if(img.complete==false) {
        all_loaded=false;
        return false;
    }
    all_loaded=true;
    return true;});
}

function CheckLoadingImages() {
    var result;
    var Checking=setInterval(function(){
         result=CheckImages();
         if(all_loaded==true) {
             clearInterval(Checking);
             MsgAfterLoading();
            }
         }, 2000);
}

function MsgAfterLoading() {
    alert('All Images Loaded');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if i is equals to the length of the array, so it will look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
        //the code
        if (i == preload.arguments.length){
            alert("Last image loaded");
        }
        //the code
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Could you try looping through all the image elements and check the naturalWidth property, if they are all greater than 0 and its the last image then alert.

This link: [Preloading Images in JavaScript (Need an Alert When Completed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132150/preloading-images-in-javascript-need-an-alert-when-completed) should help

Comment: The images are still caching, but the alert still isn't showing up with that new code. I tried putting that piece of new code elsewhere in the mix (at the end), but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you:

console.log(i, preload.arguments.length) ?

Comment: If I put in the total number of images as the variable, the alert shows, so it must be an issue with the preload.arguments.length parameter. But the alert shows up immediately, and not when all of the files are loaded into the cache. Here is what I did  if (i == 310){alert("Last image loaded") ;}

Comment: Does the alert happen before all images load, or just before the last one? If it happens before the last you could try checking the last elements natural width.

Comment: Before all of the images load. In the Chrome Developer tools, I can still see the images still being downloaded from the server even though the alert has shown.

Comment: If I use just if (i == preload.length), the alert does show now, like it did with the dummy variable 310. However, the same problem is happing again. The alert pops up immediately, and doesn't wait until all images are downloaded.

Comment: I just saw the comment about looping to check naturalWidth. Do you have any example of how to do this?

Comment: I tried this, and the alert showed at the beginning, but not at the end.                         for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
   images[i] = new Image()
   images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
   if (images[i].naturalWidth > 0){
                   alert("All images have been loaded into the browser cache.");}

Comment: What is the value of preload.arguments.length ?

Answer (score 0):

A promise might resolve your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

```
var myPromise = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    // preload code
    resolve(true);
};

myPromise.then(function() {
    // your alert
};
```

Comment: I tried it. Alert shows at the beginning, but not at the end after caching is complete (where it's supposed to). It seems to be that the array is filling, so it's prematurely fulfilling the promise while the cached downloads are still be being completed.

Comment: Maybe you should try an other way to preloads your images. This link sould be useful if you want to try something else: https://www.sitepoint.com/preloading-images-in-parallel-with-promises/
I've not tested it myself but it seems to do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onload event.

```
function PreLoadAllImages() {
  var images = new Array();
  var numberofimages = 0, loadedimages = 0;
  function preload() {
    numberofimages = preload.arguments.length;
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
      images[i].onload = () => {
         loadedimages++;
         if(loadedimages == numberofimages){
             alert("All images are loaded");
         }
      }
    }
  }

  preload('Images/Image1.jpg', 'Images/Image2.jpg', ... , 'Images/Image300.jpg');
}
```